# git assume-unchanged directory (even any new file come in the future)

Tags: git

I have to find a solution which ignore existing files like assume-unchanged but more dynamic.

I want:

- When I do `git status`, `git diff`, `git add`, etc., it just behave like there's no such a directory. (like `assume-unchanged`)
- When I do `git pull`, `git rebase`, `git reset`, `git checkout`, etc., it just behave like there's no such a directory.
- Even when I add any new file into that folder, it must still be a ghost. (what `assume-unchanged` seems cannot do)
- It's read-only so I don't have to consider about `add`, `commit`, `push`, etc.

Does anyone can help? Thanks a lot!

P.S. Some more details.  Why I have to do this is because in my project they did check-in `node_modules` directory into the repository.  If you did used msysgit with a node project on Windows, you may know the "File name too long" problem...

So I want to totally ban the `node_modules` in the repository and build my own one.  I don't need to check-in any code so I won't consider about how to check-in my changes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `node_modules` can be considered as its own repo, You could [add that `node_modules` as a submodule](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Tools-Submodules), which would make it a [simple (gitlink) entry in your index](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16581096/6309), that you can or cannot initialize.
Then you would be able to clone that same node_modules repo elsewhere (outside of your repo) for you to use.

That is different than just checking in the content of `node_modules` in an existing repo: that is about making it a repo of its own, which:

- can be included in your repo (submodule)
- can be checked out anywhere you want (in order to avoid your "Filename too long" issue)

Comment: Thanks! I believe this can really fix my problem, if the project is not read-only to me. :(
But currently I can only try to find some workaround other than to modify anything in that repository.